# Wildcard(*) SFTP in an expect script?

Tags: get, sftp, expect, qshell

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f                                      
set timeout 800                                                 
spawn sftp $env(SSH_USER)@$env(SSH_HOST) port(22)               
expect {                                                        
default {exit 2}                                                
"continue connecting (yes/no)?" {send "yes\n"; exp_continue}    
"assword:" {send "$env(SSH_PASS)\n"; exp_continue}              
"sftp>"                                                         
}                                                               
send "get /$env(SSH_FILE) /navient/$env(SSH_FILE_IMP)\r"        
expect {                                                        
default {exit 2}                                                
"not found" {exit 3}                                            
"sftp>"
```

I want to get files file the server; but, I'm trying to use a wildcard(*) for the files in a directory.

So the value for $env(SSH_File) is:
Inbox/MathewsOutbound_20240305*.CSV

The actual file name on the server is:
"MathewsOutbound_20240305hhmmss.csv"

The date and time will vary. I'm okay with the date; but, I wouldn't know what time the file was created.

I would appreciate any input. Thanks.

Roger

I listed all information above.

Comment: please post a [repro].